# ProxyPassMatch to balancers of fcgi not working

Tags: php, apache, docker, docker-compose, load-balancing

I have a docker-compose setup. Basically 3 services in it: php-fpm, apache server and mysql.

My docker-compose file, should be fine in this situation(can skip):

```
version: "3"

services:
    php-fpm:
        build: 
            context: ./bin/php-fpm
            args:
                SITE_HOSTNAME: ${SITE_HOSTNAME-example.com}
                SITE_TITLE: ${SITE_TITLE-WPBuilder}
                DOCKER_PASSWORD: ${DOCKER_PASSWORD-docker}
                MYSQL_USER_NAME: ${MYSQL_USER_NAME-wp}
                MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD-wppass}
                ADMIN_USER_NAME: ${ADMIN_USER_NAME-admin}
                ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD: ${ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD-adminpass}
                ADMIN_EMAIL: ${ADMIN_EMAIL-admin@example.com}
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        networks:
            - wp_network
        volumes:
            - "source_code:/srv/www/${SITE_HOSTNAME-example.com}"
    webserver:
        build: 
            context: ./bin/webserver
            args:
                SITE_HOSTNAME: ${SITE_HOSTNAME-example.com}
        container_name: 'wp_server'
        networks:
            - wp_network
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        depends_on:
            - php-fpm
            - mysql
        volumes:
            - "source_code:/srv/www/${SITE_HOSTNAME-example.com}"
            - "${APACHE_LOG_DIR-./logs/apache2}:/usr/local/apache2/logs/${SITE_HOSTNAME-example.com}"
    mysql:
        build:
            context: ./bin/mysql
            args:
                MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD-password}
                MYSQL_USER_NAME: ${MYSQL_USER_NAME-wp}
                MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD-wppass}
        container_name: 'wp_db'
        networks:
            - wp_network
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - "db_volume:/var/lib/mysql"
            - "${MYSQL_LOG_DIR-./logs/mysql}:/var/log/mysql"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD-password}
networks:
    wp_network:
volumes:
    db_volume:
    source_code:
```

I ran this to spin up the services, with 4 php-fpm containers in particular:

```
docker-compose up --scale php-fpm=4
```

I enter the localhost's hostname in the browser, it just returns "File not found." on the white screen.

The screen log of apache:

```
wp_server    | 192.168.144.1 - - [28/Nov/2019:17:58:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 16
```

And the access log of the first php-fpm container:

```
192.168.144.5 -  28/Nov/2019:17:58:37 +0000 "GET " 404 - 0.748 2048 0.00%
```

And finally my apache site.conf:

```
ServerName hostname

LoadModule deflate_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Proxy .php requests to port 9000 of the php-fpm container(s)
    ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" "balancer://cluster/"
    <Proxy "balancer://cluster/">
        BalancerMember fcgi://wpbuilder_php-fpm_1:9000/srv/www/hostname/$1
        BalancerMember fcgi://wpbuilder_php-fpm_2:9000/srv/www/hostname/$1
        BalancerMember fcgi://wpbuilder_php-fpm_3:9000/srv/www/hostname/$1
        BalancerMember fcgi://wpbuilder_php-fpm_4:9000/srv/www/hostname/$1
        ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
    </Proxy>

    DocumentRoot /srv/www/hostname/
    <Directory /srv/www/hostname/>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Send apache logs to stdout and stderr
    CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 common
    CustomLog logs/hostname/hostname-access_log common
    ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/2
    ErrorLog logs/hostname/hostname-error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Can someone shed light on this, this took my whole day already...thousand thanks!!

Comment: I have tested using just ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" fcgi://wpbuilder_php-fpm_1:9000/srv/www/hostname/$1, it works. But then it becomes 404 when I make it to a load-balancing setup.

Answer (score 2):

It's been solved:

apache site virtual host config:

```
ServerName hostname

LoadModule deflate_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Proxy .php requests to port 9000 of the php-fpm container(s)
    <Proxy balancer://cluster>
        BalancerMember fcgi://wpbuilder_php-fpm_1:9000
        BalancerMember fcgi://wpbuilder_php-fpm_2:9000
        BalancerMember fcgi://wpbuilder_php-fpm_3:9000
        BalancerMember fcgi://wpbuilder_php-fpm_4:9000
        ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
    </Proxy>

    DocumentRoot /srv/www/hostname
    <Directory /srv/www/hostname>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        <FilesMatch \.php$>
            SetHandler proxy:balancer://cluster
        </FilesMatch>
    </Directory>

    # Send apache logs to stdout and stderr
    CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 common
    CustomLog logs/hostname/hostname-access_log common
    ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/2
    ErrorLog logs/hostname/hostname-error_log 
</VirtualHost>
```

The key is to use FilesMatch instead of the ProxyPassMatch way.